# How to get ip network connection version (is it IPv4 or IPv6) in xamarin?

Tags: c#, android, ios, xamarin, ip

I am trying to find out how to check network connection for the ip version (IPv4 or IPv6). Application have to handle switching between networks with different ip versions. 
In android I tried to use ConnectivityManager or NetworkInterface classes. Also had an idea to search in Resources of device.
And investigated the same check for ios.
 But there is no results. May be I'searching in wrong direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced this problem before. Our app is rejected for the reason of IPv4 and IPv6 issue. I found out the IPVersion of my network through different websites. I took screenshots of the network I connected to on mobile and sent those screen shots to apple for review(saying it's a proof of connecting to IPv6).

Here below are the couple of sites that help you in finding out which version you are using.

[Check network using google](http://ipv6test.google.com/)

[Test IPv6](http://test-ipv6.com/)

**Note:** Please ignore this answer if you are looking for finding out programmatically.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have chosen [check ipv4](https://ipv4.google.com) and [check  ipv6](https://ipv6.google.com) resources and it works.

Comment: also System.Net.Ping Nuget package is useful